# Why does slicing the result of a ReadString() operation result in weird output?

Tags: go, concatenation

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Printf("Input: ")
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Println("thing\n"[:5] + "\"")
    fmt.Println(input[:len(input)-1] + "\"")

    return
}
```

Running the code:

```
Input: thing
thing"
"hing
```

Why does the second concatenation behave oddly? It should produce identical results, assuming the ReadString() operation returns a string with a newline at the end. Please explain what is going on here.

Comment: Are you on windows? Not reproducible on linux

Comment: @zerkms I am on Windows. Your answer fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're presumably on windows.

The actual input you make from your keyboard is not `thing\n` but `thing\r\n`

So when you do `fmt.Println(input[:len(input)-1] + "\"")` it only truncates the latest `\n` and leaves `\r`.

So the terminal prints `thing`, then reaches `\r` that returns carriage to the beginning of the string, then you print a double quote. But the carriage is in the first position now, and it effectively overwrites the first character of the line, leaving you with `"hing`